# How to sum the properties of an object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My input is a JSON object in the form:

```
{
  "baskets": [{
    "id": 127,
    "name": "name 1",
    "kpIs": [{
      "id": 419,
      "name": var a1, "incentive": 0, "target": "0", "actual": 0, "description": null
    }, {
      "id": 420,
      "name": var a2, "incentive": 0, "target": "0", "actual": 0, "description": null
    }],
    "percentage": 0
  }, {
    "id": 128,
    "name": "name 2",
    "kpIs": [{
      "id": 421,"name": "var b1","incentive": 0,"target": "0","actual": 0, "description": null
    }, {
      "id": 422, "name": "var b2","incentive": 0,"target": "3", "actual": 0, "description": null
    }, {
      "id": 423, "name": " var b3","incentive": 0,"target": "5.6","actual": 0,"description": null
    }, {
      "id": 424,"name": " var b4", "incentive": 0, "target": "2", "actual": 0, "description": null
    }],
    "percentage": 0
  }],
  "id": 23,
}
```

I would like to calculate the totals (target, incentive and actual) for each nested object and the overall totals for the object. I have bound the object to a table: [image].

```
            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped w-100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-label="KPI Basket" scope="col">KPI Basket</th>
                        <th data-label="KPIs" scope="col">KPIs</th>
                        <th data-label="Tgt figures" scope="col">Target</th>
                        <th data-label="Tgt figures" scope="col">Actual</th>
                        <th data-label="Incentive" scope="col">Incentive</th>
                        <th data-label="% of Total" scope="col">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                 <tbody *ngFor="let data of document.baskets; let i = index">
                    <tr style="margin: auto;" *ngFor="let obj of data.kpIs">
                        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ obj.target }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                [(ngModel)]="obj.actual"
                                name="actual{{j}}"
                                class="form-control"
                                (change)="performOperations(obj.actual, obj.target, obj.incentive  )"
                            />
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ obj.incentive }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input
                            type="number"
                            [(ngModel)]="individualTotal"
                            name="individualTotal{{j}}"
                            class="form-control"
                        />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-label="KPI Basket" scope="row"></th>
                        <strong> <td data-label="KPIs">Sub-total</td></strong>
                        <td data-label="Incentive">{{ subTotal }}</td>
                        <td data-label="% of Total"></td>
                        <td data-label="Tgt figures"></td>
                        <td data-label="Tgts"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody> 
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <strong>
                            <tr data-label="KPIs">
                                Total
                            </tr></strong
                        >
                        <td data-label="KPI Basket" scope="row"></td>
                        <td data-label="Incentive"></td>
                        <td data-label="% of Total"></td>
                        <td data-label="Tgt figures">35</td>
                        <td data-label="Tgts">35</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The sub total field is supposed to add the totals for the nested objects name 1 and name 2. then the Total field is supposed to have an overall total for the object. How can i achieve this?

Comment: `Sub Total` is sum of `Target` only, and `Total = Target + Actual + Incentive`. Is that correct?

Comment: The sub total is for the actual column, which is input in a text box. Then the total is the actual * incentive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going for the calculation as per the comment,

> The sub total is for the actual column, which is input in a text box. Then the total is the actual * incentive – user9913710

```js
const data = {
  baskets: [{
      id: 127,
      name: "name 1",
      kpIs: [{
          id: 419,
          name: "var a1",
          incentive: 0,
          target: 0,
          actual: 0,
          description: null,
        },
        {
          id: 420,
          name: "var a2",
          incentive: 0,
          target: 0,
          actual: 0,
          description: null,
        },
      ],
      percentage: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 128,
      name: "name 2",
      kpIs: [{
          id: 421,
          name: "var b1",
          incentive: 0,
          target: 0,
          actual: 0,
          description: null,
        },
        {
          id: 422,
          name: "var b2",
          incentive: 0,
          target: 3,
          actual: 0,
          description: null,
        },
        {
          id: 423,
          name: " var b3",
          incentive: 0,
          target: 5.6,
          actual: 0,
          description: null,
        },
        {
          id: 424,
          name: " var b4",
          incentive: 1,
          target: 2,
          actual: 2,
          description: null,
        },
      ],
      percentage: 0,
    },
  ],
};

const basketTotal = data.baskets.map((basket) => {
  // total = actual * incentive;
  basket.kpIs = basket.kpIs.map((kpi) => ({
    ...kpi,
    total: kpi.actual * kpi.incentive,
  }));
  // sub-total = sum(actual);
  const subTotal = basket.kpIs.reduce((total, kpi) => {
    return total + kpi.actual;
  }, 0);

  return { ...basket, subTotal };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(basketTotal, null, 2));
```

Comment: P.S: 75% of the code was generated using Copilot. #Amazing